# The verb "comprise" Is there any "necessity" to be divided into transitive or intransitive?

Tags: word-usage

Anytime I encounter this verb, "comprise", it makes me wonder why there are transitive ( mostly ) and intransitive ( often with the preposition, of ).

Especially considering the definition of 5 a of the transitive and the definition of the intransitive. ( As is shown below )

From Merrian U[image: Merrian U.]

Is there **any instance** when we should particularly use the intransitive ( and vise versa ).

Or to say in another words, is there any definite distinction **between** them?

Comment: It's not that your question is too broad; rather I do not understand what you mean by ' "necessity" to be divided '.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Transitive 5a: *the fortress comprises many miles of entrenchment*; intransitive: *the funds comprise of members' subscriptions*. If *of* is optional, then *the funds comprise members' subscriptions* ~? *the fortress comprises many miles of entrenchment*. (I think that's what they're aiming at.)

Comment: One meaning of the transitive is "has within it" and the other meaning is "constitutes" and the intransitive meaning is "is constituted of".  *The subject of the predication changes accordingly*.

Comment: The prison comprises 250 cells.   The capacity of the prison shall comprise of 200 dual-bunk  and 50 solitary-confinement cells.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you for your comment. Though, is there any "distinctive", "crystal clear" definition to "divide" them.? Looks like the intransitive entails some sort of large institute.

Comment: You don't have to justify in your question (or anywhere) why you chose to accept a certain answer. Also, please put all your comments about answers under the answers you reference; your question isn't really the right place to put them because the answerers won't be pinged and so they won't know if you have any suggestions/requests for clarification.

Comment: @userr2684291 The reason why I added the reason is because I had some kind of problems regarding this link[https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168577/norms-a-negative-word] question. But thank you for your advice.

Comment: @KentaroTomono There was no reason to give an explanation there either. You don't have to put this much thought into this. (No one will get offended if you don't accept their answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Comprises** *is* as you say, a transitive verb. It only requires a direct object, and therefore...

> the fortress comprises (verb) many miles of entrenchment (object)

... is quite correct.

"**Comprised of**" *is* used as an expression, but it is technically incorrect. "Comprises" means "consists of", so the "of" *is* redundant. And yet it is quite widely used! I didn't realise how widely until I Googled it - the expression has found its way into legal language in the US.

So to answer your question of "is there a necessity" - **no**, there isn't.

But everyday English is full of redundancies:

- "Reverted back"
- "past histories"
- "the reason for this"

Once an incorrect expression starts to be used, it can spread like wildfire because often people learn language by "chunking"; that is imitating phrases and expressions rather than learning the intricacies of how that phrase has been put together.

Comment: hmmmm  interesting. Thank you. However, to non native speakers, it goes right straight to their mind "What a..."

Comment: @Kentaro Tomono: Sorry, but I do not know what fills the blank space.  "subtle and expressive language that combines the best and worst of German and French" ?

Comment: @KentaroTomono English speakers find lots of things in other languages strange. Having to think about whether a table is male or female before referring to it. And *pomme de terre*??? It's nothing like an apple. But you accept these things just as we accept (and love) our own language. Personally I feel that English is a *living* language, always evolving (admittedly not always for the better, but still).

Comment: @Astralbee There's no such thing as **natural** *devolution* of a **living** language. Therefore, when you say "not [...] for the better", that's entirely subjective (it's hard to adapt). I'd say, as is the case with the evolution of anything, there's a tendency towards optimization. In language, that might, for example, reflect in reduction of forms unnecessary to convey information (e.g., I think we'd both agree that forms *thou* and *thee* are unnecessary to convey what *you* does today – and I'd bet you don't think there's anything wrong with using *you* instead of *thee* and so on).

Comment: @userr2684291 Well that depends on how you define "devolution". There has never been any such thing as a "simple" language, with nearly all ancient languages being far more complex that modern ones. Reduction in the number of words within a language could arguably be called "devolution" as the language operates on a "lower level". Anyway, you've taken a throwaway comment *from* a native English speaker *to* a non-native speaker who had already expressed frustration with the way we have flippantly disregarded a rule of our own language. Not worth arguing over.

Comment: @Astralbee But, you realize that in *comprised of*, *comprised* took on another meaning, right? (Namely, something similar to *consist*.) So there's nothing lost there overall. Maybe there's simply a tendency in Present-day English to spell out these implicit *of*s. I guess what I'm saying is that your definition of *devolution* is lacking. You can still express the same sentiments that English-speaking people did centuries ago. So what exactly has devolved? What I'm seeing in the *thou* example is efficiency (*you* subsumes all four forms). Wouldn't you agree that that's in fact better?

Comment: Ancient languages weren't any more complex than modern ones. What the modern ones lost in terms of morphology, they've gained in syntax, etc. And if a form was lost, it was probably because either the culture changed (the line between informal and formal has become rather blurred, so we don't need to distinguish *thou* and *thee* from *ye* and *you*, for example, or some machine or way of doing something isn't present anymore), or there's a more efficient way of saying something. *"Technically" wrong* has no say in natural language; the way people **communicate** can only be the right way.

Comment: Is there then no way to use "comprised" like if I say "The fortress is comprised ___"? Would it rather be that "Many miles of entrenchment comprised the fortress"?

Comment: @PremierBromanov You can say *The fortress is comprised of many miles of entrenchment*, or *The fortress comprises many miles of entrenchment*, or *Many miles of entrenchment comprise the fortress*.

Comment: Please read the new answer by Joce. Even Oxford says it's usage is **incorrect**.

Comment: @KentaroTomono No, it says it's regarded by some random prescriptivists as "incorrect". Here's what MWDEU says about this (an actual usage dictionary): "[T]he aspersed […] passive construction [has been in use] for more than a century. It is a little hard to understand why [this construction that is] so obviously established [is] still the source of so much discontent. […] Our advice to you is to realize that the disputed sense is established and standard, but nevertheless liable to criticism. If such criticism concerns you, you can probably avoid *comprise* by using [*other verbs*]."

Comment: (The same prescriptivists who consider the other active meaning of *comprise* (an even more attested one) "incorrect". (Whatever *incorrect* means.))

Comment: Seems to me yours is saying same sort of thing to me...

Answer (score 4):

When we say

> The funds of the association shall **comprise of** member subscriptions.

we are saying that the sole source of funding for the association shall be member subscriptions.

Another way to specify that exclusivity:

> The funds of the association shall **be comprised of** member subscriptions.

When we say

> The association's funding shall **comprise** member subscriptions.

we are not specifying anything about the exclusivity of the funding. There may be funds from sources other than member subscriptions.

> School lunches shall comprise two vegetables.
>
> School lunches shall be comprised of two vegetables.
>
> School lunches shall comprise of two vegetables.

Which sentence(s) wouldn't you want to find in the school's legal contract with the food service company?

Comment: I think you began confused, and   **comprise** is confusing.    Consider: Prepare the food in advance. The food was prepared in advance.  Compose the meal of a protein, a vegetable, and a starch. The meal is composed of a protein, a vegetable, and a starch.   These verbs are essentially transitive.  The perfect state (when the PP is used adjectivally) harbors a transitive operation.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford dictionary of English [discusses this in a note](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comprise):

> Comprise primarily means ‘consist of’, as in the country comprises twenty states. It can also mean ‘constitute or make up a whole’, as in this single breed comprises 50 per cent of the Swiss cattle population. When this sense is used in the passive (as in the country **is comprised of** twenty states), it is more or less synonymous with the first sense (the country comprises twenty states). **This usage is part of standard English, but the construction comprise of**, as in the property comprises of bedroom, bathroom, and kitchen, **is regarded as incorrect**.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169351/the-verb-comprise-is-there-any-necessity-to-be-divided-into-transitive-or-in/169356#comment338898_169356 and MWDEU's comment at **comprise** (p.273 in my version).